# CoreData has problems with sync data to cloud on a MacOS app due to pending request error

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit, swift5

I am writing an app for MacOS and main feature will be syncing data to iCloud. All that I've already done is 
- project with Core-Data and CloudKit options turned on, 
- created a model and some basic routine to create model by importing file to app.

Since this is a large file, I am doing all actions in separate thread/dispatching a new queue. When I am debugging app, saving data to local db works fine, then data is syncing to cloud when app loose its focus and I have to say that it works, what I can say by querying the data in CloudKit dashboard. But there is a problem with syncing the data when I start import of the file and when during import I will switch to other app. After import finishes, I see the data is stored locally but it cannot sync to cloud. Instead I see the following error in console:

> CoreData: debug: CoreData+CloudKit: -PFCloudKitThrottledNotificationObserver noteRecievedNotification:: : Got: NSApplicationWillBecomeActiveNotification - 0
>   CoreData: debug: CoreData+CloudKit: -PFCloudKitThrottledNotificationObserver noteRecievedNotification:: : Got: NSApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification - 1
>   CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -PFCloudKitThrottledNotificationObserver noteRecievedNotification::  - Already scheduled a block to respond to 'NSApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification', 2 notifications since.
>   CoreData: debug: CoreData+CloudKit: -[PFCloudKitThrottledNotificationObserver noteRecievedNotification:]_block_invoke(49): : Executing 'AppActivateObserver' block for 'NSApplicationWillBecomeActiveNotification' clearing 2 iterations.
>   CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate _scheduleAutomatedExportWithLabel:activity:completionHandler::  - Beginning automated export - AppActivationExport:
>   (null)
>   CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate executeMirroringRequest:error:: : Asked to execute request:  41AA55D5-F8A9-4EA9-A12A-9CA05775EC03
>   CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate _scheduleAutomatedImportWithLabel:activity:completionHandler::  - Beginning automated import - AppActivationImport - in response to activity:
>   (null)
>   CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate executeMirroringRequest:error:: : Asked to execute request:  3D212164-ABDF-4A44-A31D-1D5A9B19A9D9
>   CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate _enqueueRequest:]_block_invoke(714): : enqueuing request:  41AA55D5-F8A9-4EA9-A12A-9CA05775EC03
>   CoreData: warning: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate _enqueueRequest:]_block_invoke_2(724): Failed to enqueue request:  41AA55D5-F8A9-4EA9-A12A-9CA05775EC03
>   Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134417 "Request ' 41AA55D5-F8A9-4EA9-A12A-9CA05775EC03' was cancelled because there is already a pending request of type 'NSCloudKitMirroringExportRequest'." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Request ' 41AA55D5-F8A9-4EA9-A12A-9CA05775EC03' was cancelled because there is already a pending request of type 'NSCloudKitMirroringExportRequest'.}
>   CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate _scheduleAutomatedExportWithLabel:activity:completionHandler:]_block_invoke(2174):  - Finished automatic export - AppActivationExport - with result:  success: 0 madeChanges: 0 error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134417 "Request ' 41AA55D5-F8A9-4EA9-A12A-9CA05775EC03' was cancelled because there is already a pending request of type 'NSCloudKitMirroringExportRequest'." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Request ' 41AA55D5-F8A9-4EA9-A12A-9CA05775EC03' was cancelled because there is already a pending request of type 'NSCloudKitMirroringExportRequest'.}
>   CoreData: warning: CoreData+CloudKit: -NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate finishedAutomatedRequestWithResult:: Finished request ' 41AA55D5-F8A9-4EA9-A12A-9CA05775EC03' with result:  success: 0 madeChanges: 0 error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134417 "Request ' 41AA55D5-F8A9-4EA9-A12A-9CA05775EC03' was cancelled because there is already a pending request of type 'NSCloudKitMirroringExportRequest'." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Request ' 41AA55D5-F8A9-4EA9-A12A-9CA05775EC03' was cancelled because there is already a pending request of type 'NSCloudKitMirroringExportRequest'.}
>   CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate _enqueueRequest:]_block_invoke(714): : enqueuing request:  3D212164-ABDF-4A44-A31D-1D5A9B19A9D9
>   CoreData: warning: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate _enqueueRequest:]_block_invoke_2(724): Failed to enqueue request:  3D212164-ABDF-4A44-A31D-1D5A9B19A9D9
>   Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134417 "Request ' 3D212164-ABDF-4A44-A31D-1D5A9B19A9D9' was cancelled because there is already a pending request of type 'NSCloudKitMirroringImportRequest'." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Request ' 3D212164-ABDF-4A44-A31D-1D5A9B19A9D9' was cancelled because there is already a pending request of type 'NSCloudKitMirroringImportRequest'.}
>   CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate _scheduleAutomatedImportWithLabel:activity:completionHandler:]_block_invoke(2150):  - Finished automatic import - AppActivationImport - with result:  success: 0 madeChanges: 0 error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134417 "Request ' 3D212164-ABDF-4A44-A31D-1D5A9B19A9D9' was cancelled because there is already a pending request of type 'NSCloudKitMirroringImportRequest'." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Request ' 3D212164-ABDF-4A44-A31D-1D5A9B19A9D9' was cancelled because there is already a pending request of type 'NSCloudKitMirroringImportRequest'.}
>   CoreData: warning: CoreData+CloudKit: -NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate finishedAutomatedRequestWithResult:: Finished request ' 3D212164-ABDF-4A44-A31D-1D5A9B19A9D9' with result:  success: 0 madeChanges: 0 error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134417 "Request ' 3D212164-ABDF-4A44-A31D-1D5A9B19A9D9' was cancelled because there is already a pending request of type 'NSCloudKitMirroringImportRequest'." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Request ' 3D212164-ABDF-4A44-A31D-1D5A9B19A9D9' was cancelled because there is already a pending request of type 'NSCloudKitMirroringImportRequest'.}
>   CoreData: debug: CoreData+CloudKit: -PFCloudKitThrottledNotificationObserver noteRecievedNotification:: : Got: NSApplicationWillResignActiveNotification - 0
>   CoreData: debug: CoreData+CloudKit: -PFCloudKitThrottledNotificationObserver noteRecievedNotification:: : Got: NSApplicationDidResignActiveNotification - 1
>   CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -PFCloudKitThrottledNotificationObserver noteRecievedNotification::  - Already scheduled a block to respond to 'NSApplicationDidResignActiveNotification', 2 notifications since.

So what is said above - `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134417` - cannot execute request because there is one pending... Looks like sync action is triggered twice...

Also, what I want to mention is - the app will sync correctly when I will restart app...

So now, all I do is:

1. AppDelegate:

```
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "TestContainer")
//        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error)")

            }

            container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy(merge: .mergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicyType)
        })
        return container
    }()
```

and I've found some good practice to set merge policy as I did: `container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy(merge: .mergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicyType)`

2. After import is finished in ViewController

```
do {
    try managedContext!.save()
    managedContext?.commitEditing()    
} catch {
    print(error)
    return
}
```

And then is this problem with error in sync data as I mentioned above. For development I am using macOS 10.15.4 with Swift 5.2... Any hints? Probably there is some problem that I do not see at the moment. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I have the same issue.

Comment: managedContext?.commitEditing() what is this for?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not. This is issue with my side project so I had to focus on other things. But I wish to be back to this project :)